# Бесконечная авторизация при добавлении VKScope.MESSAGES в требуемые разрешения в android VK SDK

Tags: android, android-vksdk, vk-sdk

В новой открытой activity, которая появляется при авторизации с помощью vk sdk происходит бесконечная авторизация при добавлении в разрешения VKScope.MESSAGES, если убрать данное разрешения, то авторизация проходит моментально

Answer (score 1):

Погуглил еще, видимо вк запретили доступ к сообщениям и надо его запрашивать отдельно вместе с модерацией.